# C++: Macro that operates on scope

Tags: c++, macros

How can I construct a macro that will take this:

```
MY_MACRO(arg1, arg2) {
  doA();
  doB();
}
```

and turn it into an equivalent

```
{
  auto helper = MyClass(arg1, arg2);
  doA();
  doB();
}
```

I was thinking about something along the lines

```
#define MY_MACRO(x, y) ClassHelper(x, y) + []()
```

But I am not sure if there are some pitfalls (passing the lambda after all) or if there is some better trick to do this.

Comment: Don't use macros when you don't have to. Have a look at template functions

Comment: And you never have to in C++: or at least I've never found a case in over 30 years. You have inline functions: use them.

Comment: Bjarne is trying hard to retire macros for good. Never consider macros as primary solution; I would say macros are effectively one-past-the-end approach in C++.

Comment: @Red.Wave Not only Bjarne, though he did heavily contribute to the C++ coreguidelines. And those have some interesting things to say about (not) using macros : e.g. https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es31-dont-use-macros-for-constants-or-functions

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest making it into a function template:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <class A, class B, class... Funcs>
void instead_of_macro(A&& arg1, B&& arg2, Funcs&&... funcs) {
    auto helper = MyClass(std::forward<A>(arg1), std::forward<B>(arg2));
    (..., std::forward<Funcs>(funcs)());
}
```

Which could then be called like this:

```cpp
instead_of_macro(arg1, arg2, [] {
    doA();
    doB();
});
```

or like this:

```cpp
instead_of_macro(arg1, arg2, doA, doB);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h7z95xaKG)

Comment: Do you need the std::forward when calling func?

Comment: @BillLynch Not strictly needed here but since `Func` is a forwarding reference, I show that `func` can be forwarded to another function if needed.

Comment: This is not as convenient for me because I also need to capture potentially variables from the outside. But perhaps in my case this:
```instead_of_macro(arg1, arg2, [&] {```
would be OK.

Comment: @gruszczy Sure, that'll work.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't even need macros or function templates. The argument types to your constructor are known. So you can make a function returning your helper function.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int, double)
    {
    };
};

void doA() {};
void doB() {};

// in this case templates aren't even needed
// you can make functions returning functions (e.g. a lambda)
auto make_helper_function()
{
    auto function = [&](int i, double d)
    {
        MyClass helper{ i, d }; // construct your helper
        doA();
        doB();
    };

    return function;
}


int main()
{
    auto helper_function = make_helper_function();
    helper_function(42,1.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, either of:

```
#define MY_MACRO(arg1, arg2) if (MyClass helper(arg1, arg2); true)
```

```
#define MY_MACRO(arg1, arg2) for (std::pair<int, MyClass> helper(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(0), std::forward_as_tuple((arg1), (arg2))); \
                                  helper.first == 0; \
                                  helper.first += 1)
```

As a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

#define MY_MACRO(arg1, arg2) if (MyClass helper(arg1, arg2); true)

struct MyClass {
    MyClass(int a, int b)  { std::cout << __func__ << "\n"; }
    ~MyClass() { std::cout << __func__ << "\n"; }
};

void doA() { std::cout << __func__ << "\n"; }
void doB() { std::cout << __func__ << "\n"; }

int main() {
  MY_MACRO(1, 2) {
    doA();
    doB();
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
MyClass
doA
doB
~MyClass
```

## However, I'm pretty sure both of these are dangerous.

In either case, a `break;` statement will have unexpected behavior to the user. (It won't break out of whatever containing conditional exists. It'll break out of this macro.

Similarly, for the for loop, a nested `continue;` will have unexpected behavior.

For the if_variant, an `else` statement right after this macro will also have unexpected behavior.

**So maybe don't use macros here.**

Answer (score 1):

**Use `if (...; false) {} else`.**

```
#define MY_MACRO(...) \
    if (auto helper = MyClass(arg1, arg2); false) {} else
```

This is better than `if (...; true)` suggested in the other answer, since the latter could unexpectedly interact with user's `else`, unlike this approach.